# Uncaught TypeError: registry.forEach is not a function

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to add two dojo buttons for polyline and rectangle on a map, and i have written loop for two buttons, but i am getting error :"Uncaught TypeError: registry.forEach is not a function"

Please suggest me how to solve this issue.

Create Map and add a dynamic layer
    
    
      html, body, #map{

```
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

  }
</style>
<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.10/"></script>
<script>
  var map;

  require([
    "esri/map",
    "esri/toolbars/draw",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
    "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",
    "esri/graphic",
    "esri/Color",
    "dojo/on",
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/registry",
    "dijit/form/Button", 
    "dijit/WidgetSet",
    "dojo/domReady!"],function(Map,Map,Draw,SimpleLineSymbol,SimpleFillSymbol,Graphic,Color,on,parser,registry){
    map = new Map("map", {
      basemap: "streets",  
      center: [-122.45, 37.75], 
      zoom: 13
    });
    map.on("load", createToolbar);

      registry.forEach(function(d) {
      // d is a reference to a dijit
      // could be a layout container or a button
      if ( d.declaredClass === "dijit.form.Button" ) {
        d.on("click", activateTool);
      }
    });

     function activateTool() {
      var tool = this.label.toUpperCase().replace(/ /g, "_");
      toolbar.activate(Draw[tool]);
      //map.hideZoomSlider();
    }

    function createToolbar(themap) {
      toolbar = new Draw(map);
      toolbar.on("draw-end", addToMap);
    }

            function addToMap(evt) {
      var symbol;
      toolbar.deactivate();
      //map.showZoomSlider();
      switch (evt.geometry.type) {           
        case "polyline":
          symbol = new SimpleLineSymbol();
          break;
        case "Rectangle":
          symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
          break;
      }
      var graphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, symbol);
      map.graphics.add(graphic);
    }


    });
     </script>
```

Draw Rectangle
    Draw PolyLine

Answer (score 1):

The main issue you are having is that you have **Map** defined twice on the following line.

```
function(Map,Map,Draw,SimpleLineSymbol,SimpleFillSymbol,Graphic,Color,on,parser,registry){
```

Change that to ...

function(Map,Draw,SimpleLineSymbol,SimpleFillSymbol,Graphic,Color,on,parser,registry){

and the error seems to go away (sample doesn't seem to work yet for me but it does fix the error). This is probably because all the other objects are out of sequence after setting Map twice. You aren't using Button or Widget Symbol but maybe that comes later.

I don't know why you'd be using version 3.10 of the API. The sample I found that is similar to this uses 3.15.

see [ArcGIS Javascript API Sample - Toolbar Draw](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/toolbar_draw.html)